# CodeAnalysis.SupperssMessage is not working to suppress compilation warnings

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

following is the code which i am using to suppress the compilation warnings.

> [assembly:
>   System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming",
>   "CA1704:IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly", MessageId = "Rackable",
>   Scope = "member", Target = "Ipak.Hardware.Misc")]

and the warning are coming for an public static propertyname method of a nested call of a partial class.

the error message is "CA1704 : Microsoft.Naming : Correct the spelling of 'Rackable' in member name 'Hardware.Misc.Rackable' or remove it entirely if it represents any sort of Hungarian notation. "

the above code is working fine for other warnings.

pleae suggest if any thing is wrong with the code or scenario.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "public static propertyname method of a nested call of a partial class" but the Target must be the full name of the member. If there is nested class it would be something like "Namespace.PartialClass+Nested.Property". You could also try applying the attribute directly to the member.

Comment: its a property of a nested class of a partially implemented class. sorry for making u confuse.. and thnx for the suggestion.  i will try it.